# geom_bar and geom_point in the same ggplot and within the same groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the current code

```
ggplot(data = niveles[niveles$departamento=="CUNDINAMARCA" &
                        niveles$prueba=="MATEMÁTICAS" &
                        !is.na(niveles$nivel),]) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(),
           aes(x = año, y = desempeño, fill = nivel)) +
  geom_point(data = niveles[niveles$prueba=="MATEMÁTICAS" &
                              niveles$departamento=="COLOMBIA" &
                              !is.na(niveles$nivel),], shape = 24,
             aes(x = año, y = desempeño, group = nivel, fill = "blue"))
```

which gives me the following plot:

[image]

However, I was hoping to get each one of the "points" withing its corresponding category of the "niveles" variable. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can dodge points the same way as you dodge bars using `position=position_dodge()`. However, you need to add a `width` argument specifying how much to "dodge". A value of 1 should correspond with the dodged bars. You also have an unknown "blue" category in the legend. That's because the `fill` argument should appear outside the aesthetic (`aes`)

I also think you should subset the data first instead of doing all that within the ggplot command.

An alternative is to *facet* by department (see option 2 below).

But first to dodge the points.

**Option 1: Subsetting**

Create a subset for prueba and non-missing for nivel:

```
MATH <- niveles[niveles$prueba=="MATEMÁTICAS" & !is.na(niveles$nivel),]
```

Create subsets for each department:

```
CUNDINAMARCA <- MATH[MATH$departamento=="CUNDINAMARCA",]
COLOMBIA <- MATH[MATH$departamento=="CUNDINAMARCA",]
```

Then make your graph:

```
ggplot(data = CUNDINAMARCA) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(),
           aes(x = año, y = desempeño, fill = nivel)) +
  geom_point(data = COLOMBIA, shape = 24,
         position = position_dodge(width=1), # You need this to align points with bars
         aes(x = año, y = desempeño, group = nivel), fill = "blue")
```

---

I can't test it on your data but I used the mtcars dataset as an example.

```
mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(gear=factor(gear), cyl=factor(cyl))

VS0 <- mtcars[mtcars$vs==0,]
VS1 <- mtcars[mtcars$vs==1,]

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = VS0, stat="identity", position = position_dodge(),
           aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = gear)) +
  geom_point(data = VS1, shape = 24, 
    position = position_dodge(width=1),
    aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, group = gear), fill = "blue")
```

[image]

---

**Option 2: Facetting**

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, group=vs) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(),
           aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = gear)) +
  facet_grid(~vs, labeller=label_both)
```

[image]

---

For your data, maybe this would work:

```
DATA <- MATH[MATH$departamento %in% c("CUNDINAMARCA","COLOMBIA"),]

ggplot(data = DATA, group=departamento) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(),
           aes(x = año, y = desempeño, fill = nivel)) +
  facet_grid(~departamento, labeller=label_both)
```